# Error while installing zabbix.. Skipping architecture in Zabbix

Tags: zabbix, zabbix-api, zabbix-custom-reports

Last some days I'm working to install Zabbix in Ubuntu 22.04 but after installing .deb file the updates put some errors like ...

> N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/6.4/ubuntu-arm64 jammy InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
>
> N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'https://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/6.4/ubuntu-arm64 jammy InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'amd64'

can't go further in the deployment. is there any solution?

Comment: This question is better asked in an IT exchange like https://serverfault.com/
regardless, it looks quite reasonable that 'arm64' repo doesn't support i386 or amd64. 
I would just clean the APT/deb caches and try to reinstall. 

If you need any further help I suggest posting the question is serverfault, and provide more elaborate details.